# Are the measurement outcomes of an observable gaussian distributed?

Tags: experimental-physics, measurements, probability, error-analysis, statistics

Suppose in an experiment we perform $n$ independent measurements to find the true value of an observable $X$. Let the outcomes of $n$ measurement are denoted by $x_1,x_2,...x_n$. If $n$ is sufficiently large, will these measured outcomes $\{x_i\}$ be Gaussian distributed?

Please note that I am not asking whether the means of the measurements are Gaussian distributed. I know they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly possible to identify an observable with a non-Gaussian distribution.

An example from my professional life was a detector which collected Cherenkov photons from relativistic electrons. We needed the same detector to be sensitive to a macroscopic electron current (nanoamps) but also, with a gain change, to be able to trigger on single electrons. In the counting mode we determined that each electron sent about ten photons to the photomultiplier --- a number small enough that we had to account for the asymmetry in the Poisson distribution ($10\pm\sqrt{10}$) rather than using the Gaussian approximation.

Comment: My question is more elementary. According to Central Limit theorem, a large number of *means* obtained from several sets of independent measurements is known to follow a Gaussian distribution. My question is not about the means but about whether the measurements themselves are Gaussian distributed.

Comment: My answer is an example of a measurement whose results were Poisson distributed.

Comment: I see. So it is not necessary that the outcomes be Gaussian-distributed but the means are always Gaussian distributed. Am I right?

Comment: That question about the central limit theorem might fit better in a statistics community.

Comment: There is no reason why a set of measurements must be Gaussian. It could literally be anything. Poisson, range, bactrian camel back...

Comment: @my2cts Thanks. That's what I wanted to confirm. One more thing. Can we say that the means are always Gaussian distributed no matter how the measurements are distributed?

Comment: @mithusengupta123 Suppose you have a Poisson-distributed process with true mean 0.5 (meaning sometimes zero events, sometimes one event, rarely two events, more rarely more than two). Suppose you measure this mean many times and get 0.51, 0.46, 0.35, etc. A true Gaussian distribution with symmetric wings would predict, rarely, that you'd sometimes collect a distribution with negative mean ... but no such Poisson distribution exists. The central limit theorem is, in that sense, an approximation.

Comment: But when particle physicists talk about "sigma"s and the way they interpret it, seems that they do have some Gaussian distribution. See this [Five Sigma - Sixty Symbols](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ThP51oPttS0)

Comment: @mithusengupta123 There's a difference between "usually" and "always."